# Socket return breaking string variable

Tags: vb.net

Very odd issue. When trying to register a new user on the server, the server will post back messages such as "OK" and "usernameTaken". Upon comparing this returned string with another string (to perform an action based on the returned value), the compare isn't working.

```
Dim backupX As New CBackup
backupX.startSocket("127.0.0.1", 8888)
Dim str1 As String = backupX.registerUser("user1", "testpass")
Dim str2 As String = "usernameTaken"

If String.Equals(str1, str2) Then
    MsgBox("Strings are Equal() ")
Else
    MsgBox("Strings are not Equal() - " & str1 & " vs " & str2)
End If
```

This results in:

[image: vbSocketProblem]

So what this shows is that even though the strings *are* equal, it sais they aren't. And the MsgBox should be saying `Strings are not Equal() - usernameTaken vs usernameTaken`, it left the `vs usernameTaken` part out completely.

What's going on here?

**Extra info on CBackup class:**

**backupX.registerUser** function:

```
Public Function registerUser(ByVal name As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    Dim md5 As New CMD5
    If name.Contains(",") Then
        Return "0-commaInName"
    Else
        Return SocketSendAndReceiveMSG("registerUser," & name & "," & md5.GenerateStringHash(password))
    End If
End Function
```

**SocketSendAndReceiveMSG** function:

```
Private Function SocketSendAndReceiveMSG(ByVal msg As String) As String
    Return socket.sendAndReceiveMSG(msg)
End Function
```

**socket.sendAndReceiveMSG** function:

```
Public Function sendAndReceiveMSG(ByVal msg As String) As String
    Dim serverStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
    sendMSG(msg & "$", serverStream)
    Return receiveMSG(serverStream)
End Function
```

**receiveMSG function**

```
Public Function receiveMSG(ByVal serverStream As NetworkStream) As String
    Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
    Dim buffSize As Integer = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)
    Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
    Form1.msg("Data from Server : " & returndata)
    Return returndata
End Function
```

Looks to be like the socket code is working just fine.. each Function returns the corresponding Functions' Return value (registerUser -> SocketSendAndReceiveMSG -> sendAndReceiveMSG -> receiveMSG). I don't see how this could be messing the `str1` string variable up like this..

Comment: Could the return bytes have contained several backspaces or similar which would cause the above?  Have you tried simply outputting the server's return bytes to see what it contains?

Comment: @Smudge202 I added `msg("Bytes Sent: " & sendBytes.Length)` to the server. It reports: `Bytes Sent: 13`. Looks good to me. EDIT: I also added a check client side; `MsgBox("str1 length: " & str1.Length & " - str2 length: " & str2.Length)`. It reports: `str1: 10024 - str2: 13`. How strange! Must have something to do with `Dim inStream(10024) As Byte` in the `receiveMSG` function.. checking it out now

Comment: If it doesn't print "vs", then maybe some older version of your code is running? Have you tried rebuilding your solution? If that's not it then maybe your method isn't getting called at all, and another similar method is...

Comment: @Meta-Knight Figured it out, solution is in a comment in Olivier Jacot-Descombes' answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on the line `If String.Equals(str1, str2) Then` and inspect both strings. Are they of the same length? Is the program stopping at your breakpoint or is another code part running?

Comment: Figured it out. Changed `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)` to `Dim bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)` and `Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)` to `Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead)`.